# Galileo's discovery of the independence of motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, physicists, galileo

It is well-known that Galileo was the first one to state that motions in different dimensions (or components) are independent of one another. Where is this in Galileo's writings?

Comment: Two main published works: [Dialogue Concerning the Two Chief World Systems (1632)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue_Concerning_the_Two_Chief_World_Systems) and [Discourses and Mathematical Demonstrations Relating to Two New Sciences (1638)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_New_Sciences)

Comment: I am guessing this refers to the motion of slow projectiles being the superposition of uniform horizontal motion and uniformly accelerated vertical motion, which leads to parabolic trajectories. This is discussed in [Two New Sciences, 4th day](https://archive.org/details/dialoguesconcern00galiuoft/page/244/mode/2up). However, air resistance to fast projectiles is also discussed there, so Galileo was well aware that "motions in different dimensions" are not "independent" in general, see [Rose, Galileo's Theory of Ballistics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4025144).